# Web Scraper Returning Null Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I'm trying to do a data import to a local app for college basketball statistics gathered from basketballreference.com.  Currently, I have code that is able to gather the player averages and would like to extrapolate this to player totals.  Here is the URL I will use for this example: https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/players/lindell-wigginton-1.html.

Here's a subset of the code I'm working with:

```
request(url, (err, res, html) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {

        // Load page HTML
        const $ = cheerio.load(html); 

        /****** Get player Per Game stats ******/ 
        // Push each value to a stats array
        $("#players_per_game td").each((i ,el) => {
            const item = $(el).text();
            stats.push(item);
        });

        /****** Get Player Totals ******/
        $("#players_totals td").each((i ,el) => {
            const item = $(el).text();
            totals.push(item);
        });
     }
});
```

The Player per game stats get populated fine, but the player totals array remains null.  Here's the page HTML for the Per Game table that I reference in the scraper by the "players_per_game" id:

```
<table class="row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="players_per_game" data-cols-to-freeze="1"><caption>Per Game Table</caption>
```

Here's the same table where the reference in the scraper is NOT working:

```
<table class="row_summable sortable stats_table now_sortable" id="players_totals" data-cols-to-freeze="1"><caption>Totals Table</caption>
```

I then reference the `<td>` tags from there to grab the data; however, this only is working for the per game and not the player totals.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The tables are within the html comments. you need pull out the comments, then parse the tables from there.